# thymeleaf th:each not looping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

my web is read data from database and show it on table but not working as it should be.
my controller

```
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
    List<User> users = userDAO.getAllUser();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    return "hello";
}
```

my view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
    <h1>${users.get(0).username}</h1>
    <h1>${users.get(1).passw}</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>password</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
            <td th:text="${user.username}"/>
            <td th:text="${user.passw}"/>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

hello word is appear. also list content of username of first data and password on second data are also appear good. but the table contain loop data is not show up instead showing object on html code
[image]

```
<tr th:each="user : [com.pckg.model.User@414e9cef, com.pckg.model.User@72d57b3c, com.pckg.model.User@2640e7f3, com.pckg.model.User@35ef8cf9, com.pckg.model.User@f3c74f, com.pckg.model.User@592640f6, com.pckg.model.User@78f84b5e, com.pckg.model.User@313998fc]">
    <td th:text=""></td>
    <td th:text=""></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a thymeleaf view? Please show us your Spring MVC configuration.

Comment: are you mean code in pom.xml? <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: No I mean your Spring configuration.

Comment: i'm really sorry, i still fresh in this thing. can you guide me in which file and what its look like.

Answer (score 1):

as asked by Sotirios Delimanolis about spring configuration. i tried to figure out and found that the file is mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. and it redundant with the java version.

my solution, delete on xml part.

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem configuring Thymeleaf inside your project, the 'th' tag in the source file should be converted to HTML after parsing, but the generated HTML still showing the original tags.

Check the [InternalResourceViewResolver](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html)